# Let's make an attempt to answer old, unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have been looking at the unanswered questions on this site for some time (for some days tbh) and in my opinion, most of them are very intriguing and interesting and they deserved to get answered. There are interesting comments beneath the questions but there is no answers or even a partial answer. Some users might comment after some months or years to give some new updates like new findings or some new information but nobody are aware of that because OPs are inactive and they do not edit the question and so they doesn't get bumped on the main page. Eventually, the question gets cold and gets accumulated in the unanswered tab.

I do not have sufficient knowledge and lack expertise in this field but I would like some of these interesting question to get answered. I do not have enough reputation to give bounties on these question. Also, these question are already well-formatted so there is no room for editing (and thus do not get bumped on the main page).

Some honorable mentions:

- "[SE - stop firing the good guys](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/8693/se-stop-firing-the-good-guys?tab=topactivity)" is doing a commendable job in
  answering some old questions in the space exploration site (you can
  check his activity).
- "[uhoh](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/7982/uhoh)" is a master in commenting and linking questions and
  stuffs (he has a habit of linking unanswered question and giving
  some attention). He too asks good questions.
- "[usernumber](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/9527/usernumber)" also ask some good question, some of his question are
  left unanswered.

So, I would like some highly knowledgeable users here to make an effort in answering and giving some light to these questions. Note that I am not forcing anyone. Anyone who has or give a certain interest in some question might give a try, or do some edit or give some bounty and thus attract attention.

I do realize that all questions can't be answered so, I don't expect all of them to get answered but I am sure some of them will get very good answers.

Comment: I think you're right. We're going through a big growth spurt right now, and maybe with the new activity we can get some folks to take a fresh look at older questions. Perhaps select a few of your favorites and link them in an answer below. You could make it a community wiki so others can contribute. Everyone can use that as a starting point for taking a look at old stuff.

Comment: Just in case other users haven't noticed, Stack Exchange has ["unanswered" questions filter](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/unanswered) if they want to easily browse questions that are considered unanswered by Stack Exchange (no upvoted/accepted answers, contrast to "no answer").

Answer (score 8):

### Update VII [28-02-2023] ([See previous updates](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/625/revisions))

It's been a long time since I updated this list. So many good questions were posted last year but hasn't got any answer. Here are 9 posts from last year. Happy answering!

Note: Most of these question has valuable comments beneath it which can be compiled to answers.

1. [Up to what distance from the Moon does the Moon's gravity hold its exosphere before it is being cast away by solar wind?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47413/up-to-what-distance-from-the-moon-does-the-moons-gravity-hold-its-exosphere-bef)
2. [How to measure the latitude of the moon?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/how-to-measure-the-latitude-of-the-moon)
3. [What fraction of meteorites found on Earth are for practical purposes non-magnetic?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/what-fraction-of-meteorites-found-on-earth-are-for-practical-purposes-non-magnet)
4. [Why does the axis tilt (obliquity) of Earth change over time?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-does-the-axis-tilt-obliquity-of-earth-change-over-time)
5. [Is it possible that the inner Solar System formed in a different configuration to today?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/is-it-possible-that-the-inner-solar-system-formed-in-a-different-configuration-t)
6. [Does polar motion cause the Earth ellipsoid to change?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50546/does-polar-motion-cause-the-earth-ellipsoid-to-change)
7. [Will tidal heating on Jovian moons ever cease?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/49152/will-tidal-heating-on-jovian-moons-ever-cease)
8. [Titan's Atmosphere](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48144/titans-atmosphere)
9. [Would tidally locked Earth-like exoplanets necessarily have hot pole/cold pole atmospheric circulation?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/46895/would-tidally-locked-earth-like-exoplanets-necessarily-have-hot-pole-cold-pole-a)

Bonus:
[How far have stars been seen beyond the center of the Milky Way?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32794/how-far-have-stars-been-seen-beyond-the-center-of-the-milky-way)

Comment: I also left a comment at https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39313/in-terms-of-power-delivered-to-earth-what-is-the-brightest-object-in-the-sky since the question is not fully clear to me.

Comment: @ConnorGarcia Aren't you the expert for answering old questions ;-)

Comment: I think that [Did the Moon have a substantial atmosphere in the past?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41366/7982) can be moved now?

Comment: @uhoh Yes, definitely. I forgot to update. I am happy that someone is looking at this list. :)

Answer (score 6):

Questions answered till now:

1. [Why was helium hydride (HeH+) the universe's first molecule?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/30533/why-was-helium-hydride-heh-the-universes-first-molecule) (answered by @ProfRob)
2. [What are Kepler's laws (as he wrote them)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28055/what-are-keplers-laws-as-he-wrote-them/39857#39857) (answered by @Connor Garcia)
3. [How does the gravitation of Jupiter or other big planets affect Kepler's third law?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28900/how-does-the-gravitation-of-jupiter-or-other-big-planets-affect-keplers-third-l/40097#40097) (answered by @Connor Garcia)
4. [What is the farthest reported distance from observer from which a solar system body has occulted a star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/what-is-the-farthest-reported-distance-from-observer-from-which-a-solar-system-b) (answered by me)
5. [Is 486958 Arrokoth (2014 MU69 aka Ultima Thule) the only solar-system object determined to be binary by occultation?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35466/is-486958-arrokoth-2014-mu69-aka-ultima-thule-the-only-solar-system-object-det) (answered by @ConnorGarcia)
6. [Do Enceladus' geysers fall back to its surface or do they achieve escape velocity?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/37033/do-enceladus-geysers-fall-back-to-its-surface-or-do-they-achieve-escape-velocit) (answered by @Connor Garcia)
7. [How fast was the Earth spinning directly after the Moon formed?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26253/how-fast-was-the-earth-spinning-directly-after-the-moon-formed) (answered by @Connor Garcia)
8. [What is happening with these solar particles detected near the Sun that is so newsworthy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34943/what-is-happening-with-these-solar-particles-detected-near-the-sun-that-is-so-ne) (answered by @B--rian)
9. [How active was the Milky Way in its first 5 billion years?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28378/how-active-was-the-milky-way-in-its-first-5-billion-years/41503) (answered by @B--rian)
10. [How does Io's atmosphere behave locally near volcanic plumes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/37034/how-does-ios-atmosphere-behave-locally-near-volcanic-plumes) (answered by @B--rian)
11. [Assuming no light pollution, was "2C. 1406" ever visible to the naked eye?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33076/assuming-no-light-pollution-was-2c-1406-ever-visible-to-the-naked-eye) (answered by @HDE 226868)
12. [What are the 4 candidates for Planet Nine reported in 2017?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35301/what-are-the-4-candidates-for-planet-nine-reported-in-2017) (answered by @B--rian)
13. [Did the Moon have a substantial atmosphere in the past?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41366/did-the-moon-have-a-substantial-atmosphere-in-the-past) (answered by me)
14. [What is the highest resolution image of the moon taken from Earth's surface?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/what-is-the-highest-resolution-image-of-the-moon-taken-from-earths-surface) (answered by me)
15. [Could there be liquid water on Uranus? Are there any indications that there might be?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43887/could-there-be-liquid-water-on-uranus-are-there-any-indications-that-there-migh) (answered by @planetmaker)
16. [What if there was an asteroid belt with the mass of a planet?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32367/what-if-there-was-an-asteroid-belt-with-the-mass-of-a-planet) (answered by @IvanKurta)
17. [What fraction of a star's hydrogen store will be fused over its lifespan?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26650/what-fraction-of-a-stars-hydrogen-store-will-be-fused-over-its-lifespan) (answered by @ProfRob)
18. [How far away was the binary black hole that produced GW170729?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29162/how-far-away-was-the-binary-black-hole-that-produced-gw170729) (answered by @B--rian)

Comment: Isn't this list already captured by the Revival badge https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival ?  Or are you just featuring questions from your weekly list of five here?

Comment: @ConnorGarcia No, these questions were from my list of five. The two questions you answered were previously mentioned and were replaced with new one.

Comment: Great, I really appreciate this meta post!  I read it when I first joined and it inspires me to try to answer old questions!